# Rename midnight timestamp as Hour 24 of previous day

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

The below query breaks down a timestamp into the date, `forecast_day`, and hour, `forecast_hour`.

My problem is handling a timestamp of `2016-02-01 00:00:00` to return `forecast_day` of the previous day 2016-01-31 and `forecast_hour` of 24. The code below just returns `forecast_day` of 2016-02-01 and `forecast_hour` of 0 for such a timestamp.

```
select
  a.lat, a.lon,
  date_trunc('day', a.foretime - interval '5 hours')::date as forecast_day,
  extract(hour from a.foretime - interval '5 hours') as forecast_hour,
  f.windspeed as forecast,
  a.as_of - interval '5 hours' as latest_as_of
from weather.forecast f
  join (select
          foretime,
          max(as_of) as as_of,
          lat, lon
        from weather.forecast
        where date_trunc('day', foretime - interval '5 hours')::date - as_of >= interval '9 hours'
        group by foretime, lat, lon) a using (foretime, as_of, lat, lon)
```

Comment: 23:59:59 is the last second of a day.  24:00:00 doesn't exist.   0:00:00 is  the next day.  that's just how time is universally known.  If you want 0:00:00 to represent the last second of the prior day, then you need to use if/case statements to manage the 0:00:00 time as day-1.  But why?!?  0:00:00 is the 0-1 second of each day!  what it seems like you want to do is start the day at 0:00:01 but by then a whole second has passed!

Comment: @xQbert Good stuff. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `case` . . . or tricks:

```
select . . .
       (case when extract(hour from a.foretime - interval '5 hours') = 0 
             then date_trunc('day', a.foretime - interval '5 hours')::date - interval '1' day
             else date_trunc('day', a.foretime - interval '5 hours')::date
        end) as forecast_day,
       (case when extract(hour from a.foretime - interval '5 hours') = 0
             then 24
             else extract(hour from a.foretime - interval '5 hours')
        end) as forecast_hour,
```